# C Passing struct pointer in a recursive function

Tags: c

I am writing a program to solve a Connect Four like game combined with Candy Crush, where i check for every falling colored piece, if it is part of an atleast 4 long chain in horizontal, diagonal or vertical direction of the same color. After i have found a match, i resolve the whole chain and let the above pieces drop down and start looking for matches in the whole set of pieces. This time i resolve all matches at the same time before letting them fall down. I repeat that until no more matches are found. After that i drop down the next colored piece and so on. The pieces to drop down are stored in a text file, where every line holds information about the color of the piece and at which X-Location it is dropped.

My approach was to store the pieces in AVL-trees sorted by color, where i have an array of pointers of length 255 (255 different colors), that stores the root of an AVL-tree for each color.
Cause one AVL-tree only lets me store the x coordinate, every x entry is the root of another AVL-tree, that stores the y coordinate of the pieces at that x location.

Finding and resolving matches for one dropped down piece works just fine, but i have a problem finding matches and resolving for the set of pieces that fall down after the first resolve.

My idea was to recursively go through my tree of x nodes with that function:

```
//creates resolveTree of a bounded two-dimesional Area
void createResolveTreeOfArea(struct Node* root, struct Node* resolveTree, int leftBound, int rightBound) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        if ((leftBound <= root->key) && (root->key <= rightBound)) {
            createResolveTreeOfTree(root, root->rootY, resolveTree, root->key);
        }
        createResolveTreeOfArea(root->left, resolveTree, leftBound, rightBound);
        createResolveTreeOfArea(root->right, resolveTree, leftBound, rightBound);
    }
}
```

My bounded area is the smallest previously resolved x-node - 3 and biggest previously resolve x-node + 3 and "root" is the root of the color tree. resolveTree is the tree i want to fill and is empty on function call.

With createResolveTreeOfTree i want to go through every y-node and call my createResolveTree function

```
//creates resolve Tree of a whole one-dimensional Tree
void createResolveTreeOfTree(struct Node* colorTree, struct Node* root, struct Node* resolveTree, int x) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        resolveTree = createResolveTree(colorTree, resolveTree, x, root->key);
        createResolveTreeOfTree(colorTree, root->left, resolveTree, x);
        createResolveTreeOfTree(colorTree, root->right, resolveTree, x);
    }
}

//create ResolveTable for one node in one colorTree
struct Node* createResolveTree(struct Node* rootNode, struct Node* resolveTree, int x, int y)
{
    struct Node* temp = NULL;
    int count[8] = { 0 };
    check(count, rootNode, x, y); // returns matches in every 8 directions around a piece
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", count[0], count[1], count[2], count[3], count[4], count[5], count[6], count[7]);
    if ((count[0] + count[4]) >= 3)
    {
        resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x, 0);
        temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x);
        for (; count[0] > 0; count[0]--)
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y + count[0], 0);
        for (; count[4] > 0; count[4]--)
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y - count[4], 0);
    }
    if ((count[1] + count[5]) >= 3)
    {
        for (; count[1] > 0; count[1]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x + count[1], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x + count[1]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y + count[1], 0);
        }
        for (; count[5] > 0; count[5]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x - count[5], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x - count[5]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y - count[5], 0);
        }
    }
    if ((count[2] + count[6]) >= 3)
    {
        for (; count[2]; count[2]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x + count[2], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x + count[2]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y, 0);
        }
        for (; count[6]; count[6]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x - count[6], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x - count[6]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y, 0);
            
        }
    }
    if ((count[3] + count[7]) >= 3)
    {
        for (; count[3] > 0; count[3]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x + count[3], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x + count[3]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y - count[3], 0);
        }
        for (; count[7] > 0; count[7]--) {
            resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x - count[7], 0);
            temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x - count[7]);
            temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y + count[7], 0);
        }
    }
    if (resolveTree != NULL) {
        resolveTree = insert1(resolveTree, x, 0);
        temp = searchNode(resolveTree, x);
        temp->rootY = insert1(temp->rootY, y, 0);
    }
    return resolveTree;
}
```

The problem i am facing is that every recursive call of createResolveTreeOfTree is creating their own resolveTree instead of writing to the same memory address.
What i want is a resolve tree for all matches found in a bounded area.

Hope u can help me or atleast point me in the right direction

Comment: "every recursive call of createResolveTreeOfTree is creating their own resolveTree instead of writing to the same memory address" - I don't understand this part. Why would they write to the same memory address?

Comment: @user253751, I think the OP is saying they are getting a new tree instead of adding to an existing tree. (II have no time to read to look at this right now.)

Comment: what i want is that every call of createResolveTreeOfTree is adding its result to a mutual resolve tree for the whole color. I thought passing a pointer of the root of my resolveTree would do that